# The other name for gunships?

Tags: supreme-commander

Far back when I was playing Supreme Commander there were gunships, which could take off vertically and attack only land. I slightly remember that there was another name for them in general that gunship, but cant realise it. Anyone remember?

Stupid question, I know..

Here is picture of what they look like.
[image]

Comment: Are we talking a general synonym for gunships?  Or a specific synonym in Supreme Commander?

Comment: @Frank Newermind, I was looking for the name in the other language trying to find one and translate it from english. I found what I was looking for later so topic is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have different names depending on which faction you play as, but the [Tier 2 gunships](http://supcom.wikia.com/wiki/T2_gunship) are as follows:

- UEF: Stinger
- Cybran: Renegade
- Aeon: Specter
- Seraphim: Vulthoo

Comment: Thx, but I meant the general name. Like synonym to "gunships", any ideas?

Comment: They're always just referred to as "gunships" in the game. For instance, the Stinger's tooltip describes it as a "gunship".